# How to make specific time format using PHP

Tags: php, datetime-format

I need one help.I need to make one specific date time format using PHP.I need like `July 9, 2015 at 8:15 pm` format but as now i am using `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` now but its not giving any AM/PM format.Please help me to do this.

Comment: date('Y-m-d H:i:s A')

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php     check all the possible formats

Comment: Seriously, learn how to google stuff! BTW, just to prevent questions for a LMGTFY-links, `F j, Y \a\t g:i a`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date('F j, Y \a\t g:i a')
```

All the formatting characters can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get am/pm date in php

```
date('Y-m-d h:i A');
```